# Remove duplicates entries from multiple text file in perl?

Tags: perl

I am new to this site,need help to remove duplicate entries from multiple text file(in a loop).tried the below code but this is not removing duplicates for multiple files,however it is working for a single file.

Code :

```
my $file = "$Log_dir/File_listing.txt";
my $outfile  = "$Log_dir/Remove_duplicate.txt";; 

open (IN, "<$file") or die "Couldn't open input file: $!"; 
open (OUT, ">$outfile") or die "Couldn't open output file: $!"; 
my %seen = ();
{
  my @ARGV = ($file);
  # local $^I = '.bac';
  while(<IN>){
    print OUT $seen{$_}++;
    next if $seen{$_} > 1;
    print OUT ;
  }
}
```

Thanks,
arts

Comment: Try `next if $seen{$_} > 0;`

Comment: You are not opening multiple files, you have only one input file name there, so how can you possibly expect it to affect multiple files?

Comment: Are you looking for duplicates across all files, or just duplicates inside each individual file?

Comment: Please explain. Your code doesn't correspond to your description. Is `File_listing.txt` supposed to contain a list of files to be processed? If not then which files are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

The errors in your script:

- You overwrite (a new copy of) `@ARGV` with `$file`, so it can never have any more file arguments.
- ...which doesn't matter, because you open the file handle before you assign to `@ARGV`, plus you do not loop around the arguments, you just have a block `{ ... }` around the code that serves no purpose.
- `%seen` will contain dedupe data for all the files you open unless you reset it.
- You print the count `$seen{$_}` to the output file, which I am sure you don't need.

---

You could use the implicit open of `@ARGV` arguments using the diamond operator, but since you (probably) need to assign a proper output file name for each new file, that is an unwanted complication with such a solution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;                      # always use these

for my $file (@ARGV) {             # loop over all file names
    my $out = "$file.deduped";     # create output file name
    open my $infh,  "<", $file or die "$file: $!";
    open my $outfh, ">", $out  or die "$out: $!";
    my %seen;
    while (<$infh>) {
        print $outfh $_ if !$seen{$_}++;   # print if a line is never seen before
    }
}
```

Note that using a lexically scoped `%seen` variable makes the script check for duplicates inside each individual file. If you move the variable outside the for loop, you will check for duplicates across *all* files. I am not sure which you prefer.

Comment: Please edit : change !$seen{$_] to !$seen{$_}. I tried to change it myself but it requires to change 6 chars at least :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your `File_listing.txt` contains lines, some of which have multiple occurences? If that's the case, just use the bash shell:

```
sort --unique <File_listing.txt >Remove_duplicate.txt
```

Or, if you prefer Perl:

```
perl -lne '$seen{$_}++ and next or print;' <File_listing.txt >Remove_duplicate.txt
```